# Problem relationship many to many on Laravel

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship

I'm new to Laravel, I'm having this problem:
I have 2 tables, platos and ingredientes, these have a many to many relationship, and for this I use a third table called ingredientes_platos.

To save the relationship many to many I tried with the following:

$platos->ingredientes()->attach($input['ingredientes']);

but it gives the following error:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '151-3' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `ingredientes_platos` (`platos_id`, `ingredientes_id`, `norma_bruta`) values (151, 3, ))

Looking a bit in the documentation, I could solve with sync instead of attach, but this does not solve my problem, because in addition to saving the id's of the relationship I need to save other attributes in the pivot table.

It is important to note that if I try to save this data in a table other than ingredients_platos, I do not get this problem and the data is saved correctly no matter which method I use.

I appreciate your attention, I hope you can help me.

These are the models for the three tables:

**Table Platos:**

```
public $table = 'platos';


protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];


public $fillable = [
    'Grupo',
    'Nombre',
    'Procedimiento',
    'Cantidad',
    'Unidad',
    'Precio'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'Grupo' => 'integer',
    'Nombre' => 'string',
    'Procedimiento' => 'string',
    'Cantidad' => 'integer',
    'Unidad' => 'integer',
    'Precio' => 'double'
];

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
public static $rules = [
    'Grupo' => 'required',
    'Nombre' => 'required'
];

public function ingredientes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Ingredientes::class);
}

public function grupo_platos()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Grupo_Platos', 'id', 'Grupo');
}
```

}

**Table Ingredientes:**

public $table = 'ingredientes';

```
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];


public $fillable = [
    'Grupo',
    'Nombre',
    'Descripcion',
    'Kcal',
    'Proteinas',
    'Grasas',
    'Unidad',
    'Precio'
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'Grupo' => 'integer',
    'Nombre' => 'string',
    'Descripcion' => 'string',
    'Kcal' => 'double',
    'Proteinas' => 'double',
    'Grasas' => 'double',
    'Unidad' => 'integer',
    'Precio' => 'double'
];

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
public static $rules = [
    'Nombre' => 'required'
];

public function platos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Platos::class);
}
```

}

**Table Ingredientes_Platos:**

```
public $table = 'ingredientes_platos';

public $fillable = [
    'platos_id',
    'ingredientes_id',
    'norma_bruta',
    'norma_neta',
    'unidad_id'
];

public $timestamps = false;
```

}

**Platos Controller:**

```
public function store(CreatePlatosRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $platos = $this->platosRepository->create($input); 
    $id = $platos->id;

    $ingredientes = $input['ingredientes'];
    $norma_b = $input['norma_b'];

    $t = sizeof($ingredientes);

    $i=0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $t; $i++) { 

        $pivot = new Ingredientes_Platos;

        $pivot->platos_id = $platos['id'];
        $pivot->ingredientes_id = $ingredientes[$i];
        $pivot->norma_bruta = $norma_b[$i];

        $pivot->save();
    }


    Flash::success('Plato agregado correctamente.');

    return redirect(route('platos.index'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much, my problem was solved. It happens that in addition to Laravel, I'm using InfyOM and this was creating a conflict when I was trying to manually add the records to the pivot table, because this line was already responsible for adding the registry to the pivot table: $ dishes = $ this-> dishesRepository-> create ($ input);

Answer (score 0):

If you need one type to "belong" to another type multiple times, and vice versa, then the generic many-to-many relationship probably isn't a good fit for what you're trying to do. Not just because of the primary key constraint, but because you'll have cases in which multiple row results are returned for the relationship, and the many-to-many relationship won't know how to aggregate or group these. You may want to come up with a third type of `Model` that's something like an "attribute" that has relationships to the other two models and helps you accomplish your goal.

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem was solved. It happens that in addition to Laravel, I'm using InfyOM and this was creating a conflict when I was trying to manually add the records to the pivot table, because this line was already responsible for adding the registry to the pivot table:

$ dishes = $ this-> dishesRepository-> create ($ input);

Answer (score 0):

```
// Many to Many relationship in category Model to Post model coding here
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Category extends Model
{
        public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post')->withTimestamps();
    }
}

// Many to Many relationship in Post Model to Category model coding here

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Post extends Model
{

    public function categories(){
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->withTimestamps();
 }




}
```